# How do I improve the query with OR, AND clause?

Tags: mysql

How do I improve the query with OR, AND clause?

```
explain 
       select fileds 
       from table_name 
       where (fldlp>='2012-09-15 13:00:34' and fldlp<='2012-09-16 06:00:02') 
    or (flexp>='2012-09-15 13:00:34' and flexp<='2012-09-16 06:00:02');

+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_name | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2928790 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: what do you mean with "improve", in which sense?

Comment: what is the dataType of `fldIp` and `flexp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause.

```
WHERE (fldlp BETWEEN '2012-09-15 13:00:34' AND '2012-09-16 06:00:02') 
   OR (flexp BETWEEN '2012-09-15 13:00:34' AND '2012-09-16 06:00:02');
```

Comment: @diEcho Yes, But looking time in column I think it should be `datetime`

Comment: @diEcho: Would there be any difference if the datatypes were `CHAR`? The OP's query and this are equivalent anyway.

Comment: @ypercube  dateTime dataType are useful to store date and time, and btw `varchar` is even better than `char`

Comment: @diEcho: No argue there, `datetime` is to be used when one wants to store a datetimes. I was referring to the equivalence of `x BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2` and `x >= ?1 AND x<= ?2`

Comment: I think `BETWEEN AND` operator is faster than `logical comparison operator`. isn't it?

Comment: Thanks hims056... Addition to this I have added index on fldlp and flexp. And it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

tips to improve

- create index on `fldlp` and `flexp`
- dataType of above columns shoud be **dateTime**